# SVG показывает обрезанный край

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, google-chrome

Что я могу сделать, используя собственный синтаксис SVG или CSS, чтобы этот обрезанный край не появлялся в моем SVG?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#profile-pic {
  width: 33%;
}
#profile-pic text {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #000;
  -webkit-animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
          animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
@keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="profile-pic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <title>Brandon McConnell</title>
<defs>
  <clipPath id="imageClipPath"><circle cx="250" cy="250" r="116" fill="#FFFFFF" /></clipPath>
</defs>
    <text dy="70" textLength="500">Lorem Ipsum</text>
    <image
    href="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/6e25e38e140dda7ac64f7865b3df77ab?s=500"
    clip-path="url(#imageClipPath)"
    width="240"
    height="240"
         x="130"
         y="130"
  />
</svg>
```

Я вижу это в последней версии Chrome. Скриншот:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCfll.png

**Системные характеристики:**

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)    
macOS Big Sure - Version 11.6.1 (20G224)
Google Chrome - Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (x86_64)
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG shows clipped edge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69932848/7394871) от участника  [@Brandon McConnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824249/brandon-mcconnell).</sub>

Comment: ассоциациz:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69932848/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известная ошибка Chrome.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1171601

А пока можно обойтись без маски.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#profile-pic {
  width: 33%;
}
#profile-pic text {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: #000;
  -webkit-animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
          animation: raise 1s linear infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
@keyframes raise {
  from { transform: translateY(-10px); }
  to { transform: translateY(10px); }
}
```

```html
<svg id="profile-pic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <title>Brandon McConnell</title>
<defs>
  <mask id="imageClipPath"><circle cx="250" cy="250" r="116" fill="white" /></mask>
</defs>
    <text dy="70" textLength="500">Lorem Ipsum</text>
    <image
    href="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/6e25e38e140dda7ac64f7865b3df77ab?s=500"
    mask="url(#imageClipPath)"
    width="240"
    height="240"
         x="130"
         y="130"
  />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69939703/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>